# Add a column to file in linux at beginning of line if length is less than 4

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

I have a file like below on linux folder. There should be 4 columns in file with comma separated values.But in some lines there are only 3 columns. I want to add a blank at the beginning of line when there are 3 columns.

Input:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,b2,b3,b4
c2,c3,c4
d1,d2,d3,d4
```

output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,b2,b3,b4
,c2,c3,c4
d1,d2,d3,d4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use awk ex.

```
awk -F, 'NF==3 {$0=","$0} 1' file
```

If you have a suitably recent version of GNU awk you can apply it to the file in-place using

```
gawk -i inplace -F, 'NF==3 {$0=","$0} 1' file
```

Otherwise, it's probably easier to use a different tool such as `sed` or `perl`.

```
perl -i -F, -pe '$_ = "," . $_ if $#F == 2' file
```

or perhaps

```
sed -i'.bak' -e 's/,/,/3;t' -e 's/^/,/' file
```

(attempt to replace the 3rd comma, and substitute a comma at the start of line if it fails).

Comment: Thanks . Can you please let me know how can we do a infile processing

Comment: @user1024962 some in-place options added

Comment: @user1024962 the way these tools do in-place processing can be implemented like this. Consider a file called `thing`: `sed-or-awk-or-whatever '...some...options...' > thing.tmp && mv -f thing.tmp thing; rm -f thing.tmp`

Comment: I am using last option for a file having 13 columns and using as below.sed -i'.bak' -e 's/,/,/13;t' -e 's/^/,/' file. But above command is replacing all the rows with ',' at beginning

Comment: @user1024962 if the file has 13 columns, you would need to test replacement of the 12th comma (there's always one more field than delimiter)

Answer (score 3):

I propose a `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\)$/,\1/' file
```

Output

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,b2,b3,b4
,c2,c3,c4
d1,d2,d3,d4
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this works, have no machine to test it right now.

But you could always add the comma and then grep for the last four elements:

```
sed -e 's#^#,#' | grep -o -E '[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$'
```

Do you have commas inside the data fields? Then it becomes messy.